# WhenAll + ContinueWith, finally

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have three top level processes that I want to run concurrently. After two of the processes complete, I have subprocesses that need to run, one a collection that needs to run concurrently. The only problem I face is that the Flush in finally executes before the subprocesses complete. I've inserted some trace statements, and this is the result:

```
Pulling AssetList
Pulling MarketImports
Pulling AccountBalance
AccountBalance Pulled
MarketImports Pulled
Pulling WalletTransactions
AssetList Pulled
Pulling BlueprintList
Pulling MarketOrders
Pulling IndustryJobs
Flushing
MarketOrders Pulled
BlueprintList Pulled
IndustryJobs Pulled
WalletTransactions Pulled
```

How do I get Flush to occur after the subprocesses complete? The code in question follows:

```
private async Task DoPull(string token, string name, Func<string, Task> func)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Pulling {0}", name));
    await func(token);
    StopSteps(token, name);
    Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} Pulled", name));
}

try
{
    await Task.WhenAll(
        DoPull(tk, "AssetList", _assetMapper.Pull).ContinueWith(async c => await Task.WhenAll(
            DoPull(tk, "BlueprintList", _blueprintMapper.Pull), 
            DoPull(tk, "MarketOrders", _orderMapper.Pull), 
            DoPull(tk, "IndustryJobs", _jobMapper.Pull))),
        DoPull(tk, "MarketImports", _marketMapper.Pull).ContinueWith(async c => 
            await DoPull(tk, "WalletTransactions", _transactionMapper.Pull)),
        DoPull(tk, "AccountBalance", _balanceMapper.Pull));
}
catch (Exception)
{
    StopSteps(token, _running.ToArray());
}
finally { Flush(token); }
```

Answer (score 0):

**real answer**

in DoPull, once the awaited function completes, execution is returned back to the caller.  What this means is that once all the other awaits complete in the other `DoPull` calls, it will continue on back in the main method, and hit the finally block.  There is no guarantee that the `StopSteps` or `Trace.WriteLine` calls will execute before that happens.

**incorrect stuff**

The execution inside the `ContinueWith`'s are not being awaited anywhere.

You should use `ContinueWith<Task>` to get that functionality.

Also, it was kind of hard to follow along with everything inline like that, maybe break it up a bit so its easier to pick out what the steps are?

```
    private async Task Method()
    {
        try
        {
            var assetList = DoPull(tk, "AssetList", _assetMapper.Pull)
                .ContinueWith<Task>(t => Task.WhenAll(
                    DoPull(tk, "BlueprintList", _blueprintMapper.Pull),
                    DoPull(tk, "MarketOrders", _orderMapper.Pull),
                    DoPull(tk, "IndustryJobs", _jobMapper.Pull));

            var marketImport = DoPull(tk, "MarketImports", _marketMapper.Pull)
                .ContinueWith<Task>(t => DoPull(tk, "WalletTransactions", _transactionMapper.Pull));

            var accountBalance = DoPull(tk, "AccountBalance", _balanceMapper.Pull);

            await Task.WhenAll(assetList, marketImport, accountBalance);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            StopSteps(token, _running.ToArray());
        }
        finally { Flush(token); }
    }
```

**EDIT**

```
    private async Task PullAssetList()
    {
        await DoPull(tk, "AssetList", _assetMapper.Pull);

        await Task.WhenAll(
                    DoPull(tk, "BlueprintList", _blueprintMapper.Pull),
                    DoPull(tk, "MarketOrders", _orderMapper.Pull),
                    DoPull(tk, "IndustryJobs", _jobMapper.Pull));
    }

    private async Task PullMarketImport()
    {
        await DoPull(tk, "MarketImports", _marketMapper.Pull);

        await DoPull(tk, "WalletTransactions", _transactionMapper.Pull);
    }

    private async Task PullAccountBalance()
    {
        await DoPull(tk, "AccountBalance", _balanceMapper.Pull);
    }

    private async Task Method()
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.WhenAll(PullAssetList(), PullMarketImport(), PullAccountBalance());
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            StopSteps(token, _running.ToArray());
        }
        finally { Flush(token); }
    }
```

Comment: if the `ContinueWith<Task>` isnt working, maybe break it up even more?  i  edited the answer to move things to different methods and await each of them

Comment: is StopSteps doing something special?  i just ran it through and got the output i would expect, just commented out all the "real work" and `StopSteps`

Comment: you know, i ran it using the code from the second block (after Edit) and it worked. The problem with the first block is that first Task.WhenAll starts immediately. I updated the first block so it should behave correctly.

Comment: Deleted comments to keep it clean. On inspection, Edit looks correct, and in practice it works even with delays injected into DoPull. It appears that ContinueWith operates as a fire-forget even if awaited, and unless a more succinct correct answer presents Edit should be accepted.

Comment: @WinstonWolfIT: `ContinueWith` doesn't understand `async` lambdas, which is why it appears to return early. This is one of the several reasons you should (almost) always use `await` instead of `ContinueWith`. I describe [`ContinueWith` for modern apps](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/01/a-tour-of-task-part-7-continuations.html) more on my blog.